# JavaScript caret in regex not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert markdown URL's to the `<a href="" />` links. But, the same regex that is working in PHP is not working in JavaScript. What I'm doing wrong?

Regex: `\[([^]]*)\]\(([^\s^\)]*)[\s\)]`

Here is the demo link where you can see for your self:
https://regex101.com/r/kZbw7g/5

It seems that the caret has a different meaning in JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Escape `]` inside a character class. Also, note that you do not have to escape `)` inside a character class as it is not a special char there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this

```
 \[
 ( [^]]* )                     # (1)
 \]
 \(
 ( [^\s^\)]* )                 # (2)
 [\s\)]
```

This is a readable, formatted version of your regex.

There are rules governing the parsing of character classes (Non-Java/DotNet).

*The class is opened `[` and is not escaped.*

Rule #1 : The very next un-escaped `]` closes the class.

The Only *exception* is when it is the first item in the class.  `[]]`.

This exception holds for a negated class as well `[^]]` because
it is still the first *item* in the class.

This is why your regex works in the pcre demo.

HOWEVER, JS is still an antiquated engine which has no such grace for `]`
being the first item.
So, it must be  escaped.  `[\]]` and `[^\]]`

See the JS version here https://regex101.com/r/kZbw7g/6

***Adendum :***

Additionally, you can see *how/why* the grace exists for an un-escaped
`]` when it is the first item.

It seems originally, when designing *rules* for class parsing, it was
determined to *NOT* allow *EMPTY* classes `[]`.

It could be that the fix-up state was *beyond* what designers wanted to
handle. In other words, they wanted to make parsing classes a very low
intelligent thing to do.

Who knows why..

Here is the kicker, empty classes are not allowed.
If a `]` is immediately after the start of a class  (first item),
it cannot possibly be the closing `]` because, that would be an illegal
*empty* class.

However, since there is a valid closing brace `[]]`, there is no *ambiguity*,
the first item `]` is a literal.

Thus the *First Item Exception* was born.

This is the proof:

pcre https://regex101.com/r/v0uBHA/1
JS  https://regex101.com/r/foqcpL/1
Python  https://regex101.com/r/sko0Qv/1
go https://regex101.com/r/Nhx8Ks/1

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @ffox003 - You're welcome. I added an addendum that may further shed light on this strangeness.